# can't catch "ctor subscript out of range" exception in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, try-catch, subscript

I am writting a program which uses a vectors in visual studio 2012. This is the problematic fragment of my code:

```
std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<Eigen::Matrix3d> > > tensor;
//some code
try
    {
        ret = tensor[x][y][z];
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "Index out of range!" << std::endl;
    }
```

When x, y or z is out of range, program terminate instead of handle the exception.

Is it matter of some settings in VS?

Comment: The only way to answer the question as written is to guess how `tensor` is defined.

Comment: It doesn't matter how it is defined. Question was about handling exceptions thrown by vectors. Explanation that operator [] doesn't throw any exception was an answer I needed.

Comment: Um, that's nice, but your sample code does not use 'vector` anywhere, so the assertion that your program "uses vectors" in no way describes what the problem is. That makes the question a bad question, even if someone correctly guessed what it is that you were attempting to ask.

Comment: I must admit that you are right. I'll fix it.

Comment: I've changed my down vote to an up vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter if you use a vector or an array, using the array indexing operator `[]` will not throw an exception when indexing out of bounds. All you get is *undefined behavior*.

If you want bounds checking then use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and its [`at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) access function.